# SchemaException: Error reading field 'topics' in Kafka and Event Hubs

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am working with Azure Event Hubs and Kafka. I have a producer that would send messages to a topic with 4 partitions in Event Hubs. Then, 4 consumers would consume from that topic. Most of the time, it works properly. But then, I would sometimes experience this error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topics': Error reading array of size XXXXXXX, only XX bytes available
```

Can anyone give me a background on why this is happening and how to fix this?

Here is part of the logs throwing the error:

```
19/07/12 15:22:20.354 ERROR reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver: Unexpected exception
org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topics': Error reading array of size 825844834, only 33 bytes available
at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Schema.read(Schema.java:76)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerProtocol.deserializeSubscription(ConsumerProtocol.java:96)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:340)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:520)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:93)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:472)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:455)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:822)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:802)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:563)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:390)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:293)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:193)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:364)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:290)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1149)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver$PollEvent.run(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:446)
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.doEvent(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:377)
at reactor.kafka.receiver.internals.DefaultKafkaReceiver.lambda$start$16(DefaultKafkaReceiver.java:319)
at reactor.core.publisher.LambdaSubscriber.onNext(LambdaSubscriber.java:130)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:396)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:480)
at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are some component which can block or limit the usage.

1. Throughput unit
2. Ingress/Egress size

Based on the plan this would impact the performance or discard request.

You could also utilize auto-inflate mode, but would depend on the plan.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#throughput-units

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-auto-inflate

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/event-hubs/